# Finding RGB values from an jpeg image in R

Tags: r, image

I am trying to find RGB values in R.

The jpeg images that I am using have an object with white background. 
Like this one: http://www.wild-wonders.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/nba_france_16.jpg

Right now, in order to just select the object, I have to trace each object manually (by plotting dots which makes the selection into a shape that will later be used to get the RGB values). Is there any tools or packages like magic wand tool in photoshop that will automatically select the white background?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the functionality provided by the Bioconductor package **[EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage/)**, an image processing and analysis toolbox for *R*. To install the package use:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")
```

The example below illustrates how to automatically extract an object from white background, and get its #rrggbb pixel values. I used a value of 0.95  for thresholding rather than 1.0 (corresponding to white pixels) because of the artifacts introduced by jpeg compression.

```
library(EBImage)

## load the array representing pixel intensities into R
img <- readImage("http://www.wild-wonders.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/nba_france_16.jpg")

## convert to grayscale before thresholding
gray <- channel(img, "gray")

## create a mask separating objects from background
mask <- gray < 0.95

## label objects (connected sets of pixels)
obj <- bwlabel(mask)

## indices of pixels within the object
idx <- which(mask==1, arr.ind=TRUE)

## extract the red, green, and blue pixel intensities
rgb <- cbind(channel(img, "r")[idx],
             channel(img, "g")[idx],
             channel(img, "b")[idx])

## convert to #RRGGBB representation
rgb(rgb)
```